# Workflow tasks created in SharePoint Designer 2013 for SharePoint Online will NOT send "Open This Task" button to Outlook 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, outlook

We have a SPO environment and I'm creating a workflow in SPD 2013. When creating a 2013 custom workflow with a task assigned to a user, the email with the task notification does **not** include the "Open This Task" button. It only includes a link to the workflow task list "display" view. But the 2010 workflows successfully send the button with the task notification email. What's going on here? How do I get the "Open This Task" button to show in 2013 task email notifications? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between Workflow 2010 and 2013, you can change the Send Task Behaviour and add link to the email.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji5wxt4fcKc

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 0):

It is by default that there is no "Open This Task" button to show in 2013 task email notifications.

To get the "Open This Task" button to show in 2013 task email notifications, you need to create the URL in the email body manually.

Comment: The goal here is to present the Approver with the Task "editform" is as few clicks as possible from their email. I can't figure out how to present the approve/Reject options like this.  The task Url is in the email but the user would have to click "edit this item" in the task list ribbon. That one step will keep users from completing their task because they "cant figure it out". How do I create the "open this task" like you mention in your answer?